# Como ler linhas txt e inserir no Database com PHP

Tags: php

Preciso pegar o valor de cada linha e cada coluna para inserir no database, porém existem resultados que o campo Observações estão em duas linhas e na verdade é a continuação da linha anterior. Não estou conseguindo colocá-lo na continuação da linha anterior.

[Link do TXT](http://portal.cgna.gov.br/files/abas/2017-03-20/painel_rpl/companhias/Cia_AZU_CS.txt)

O resultado que eu preciso é esse:

```html
<table>
<thead>
   <tr>
       <th>IDENT ANV</th>
       <th>TIPO</th>
       <th>ADEP</th>
       <th>EOBT</th>
       <th>VEL</th>
       <th>FL</th>
       <th>ROTA</th>
       <th>DEST</th>
       <th>EET</th>
       <th>OBS</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>AZU2400</td>
       <td>E190</td>
       <td>SBGR</td>
       <td>11:25</td>
       <td>N396</td>
       <td>290</td>
       <td>DCT DORLU UZ37 VUREP DCT</td>
       <td>SBRJ</td>
       <td>00:40</td>
       <td>EQPT/SDFGHIRWY PBN/A1B1D1O1S2</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Bota, por favor, um exemplo de um comentário em duas linhas. Ele fica em dois `<td>`s diferentes, mesmo, ou só tem uma quebra de linha dentro de um único `<td>`?

Answer (score 0):

Sua fonte de dados está muito irregular.

Primeiramente ela não está usando delimitadores de quebra de linha (\n \r), o que impossibilita a leitura padronizada, o texto está todo identado por espaços, e como o campo observações aparece as vezes de forma aleatória com 10 ou 6 dígitos, fica muito difícil fazer a extração dos dados.

O que eu recomendo é você primeiro padronizar a fonte de dados e depois fazer o trabalho necessário.

No caso a expressão regular mais próxima que cheguei foi :

/\d{6}.+(\w{3,4}/\w{8,10}){1,4}/g

Mas reitero que sem quebra de linhas e sem padronização, a expressão regular não irá servir.

Para testar utilize o http://regexr.com/